# Mismatched User Data From An OAuth Provider

Tags: jhipster

With an OAuth provider, we obtain the user data which doesn't have a perfect match with the User in Jhipster. The OAuth provider doesn't handle the user role. So, we can't get the user authentication information from the provider. I can't think of a way to work around this missing user information.

Also, the OAuth provider provides a user locale, but the User entity doesn't have the locale attribute. To keep the locale information, one solution is to extend the User with another entity that has a one-to-one relationship with the User entity. Since our JHipster app is multi-language, the locale information from the OAuth provider could be saved in the JHipster app. I have a scan, I don't know related locale information in the JHipser document. How shall I go about it?

Comment: I had same situation with Azure Active Directory: the token did not contain the group, my solution was to use the AAD spring boot starter and code manually following their examples. I don't understand your other point.

Comment: I guess that your app is deployed on Azure. Our app will be deployed on AWS. I don't see any related Spring Cloud AWS project in this regard. For the locale of user data from the OAuth provider, this data could be saved as the app locale.  I haven't found how the locale is set.

Comment: Have you read https://aboutbits.it/blog/2021-03-22-aws-cognito-spring-boot-extract-roles Once you figured it out it would be great if you could contribute it to JHipster as documentation or as code to the generator.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I didn't know Amazon Cognito. I don't know whether it is applicable for our usage or not, nor we would put out an effort to use it. Our app is small and I only need to access the system information which is accessible for admin.